# Rails Devise titleize user fields not present during registration

Tags: ruby-on-rails, model, devise, title

In my users model I call a titleize method before a user is created or saved as follows:

```
before_save :titleize, :to_lower
before_create :titleize, :to_lower 

def titleize
    self.first_name = self.first_name.titleize
    self.last_name = self.last_name.titleize
    self.pursuits = self.pursuits.titleize
end
```

Which works just fine, but I have more user fields that I want titleized that can't be accessed until the user is actually registered such as bio or city. But if I throw these into my titleize method I'll get registration errors because these fields aren't actually present on the registration form. So how do I titleize these other fields without interrupting the registration?

Comment: What are the errors you're receiving?

Comment: Submitted an answer. If this isn't what you're looking for, could you clarify on "can't be accessed until the user is actually registered". Does this mean the model cannot access the attribute, or the attribute returns nil or some other condition?

Comment: I'd ask why you're modifying user inputs here. What's the point of titleizing? Is it just so the name looks better when displayed somewhere? If so, why not call titleize in the view, or create a model method like `def display_name; self.first_name.titleize + ' ' + self.last_name.titleize; end`?

Comment: I was getting undefined method 'titleize' but I just wrapped them in if statements and it's working now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can add if condition like this:-

```
before_save :titleize, :to_lower
before_create :titleize, :to_lower 

def titleize
  self.first_name = self.first_name.titleize
  self.last_name = self.last_name.titleize
  self.pursuits = self.pursuits.titleize
  if self.bio?
    self.bio = self.bio.titleize
  end
end
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's my take:

```
  def titleize
    fields_to_titleize.each { |f| self[f] = self[f].titleize }
  end

  def fields_to_titleize
    fields = [:first_name, :last_name, :pursuits, :bio, :city]
    fields.keep_if { |f| self.respond_to?(f) }
  end
```